# Html form label line breaks

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

i need a twitter bootstrap form with input text boxes on the same line, but its labels must be on the top of input boxes.

So far i have:

```
<form action="#">
  <label for="city">City</label>
  <input type="text" id="city"/>
  <label for="street">Street</label>
  <input type="text" id="street"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8RaG/

So i need inputs on the same line and labels must be on the top of each input.

How do i do that?

Comment: By "on top" do you mean like a placeholder? http://jsfiddle.net/A8RaG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a div around each label and block, and in the css put this div in inline-bloc

like :

```
<form action="#">
 <div class = "css">


 <label for="city">City</label>
  <input type="text" id="city"/>
   </div><div class="css">
  <label for="street">Street</label>
  <input type="text" id="street"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

and in the CSS:

```
.css{
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: hmm not trying to necro, but there is a typing error here and I did find this on a search so it should be corrected: inline-bloc to inline-block

Comment: I think you ment inline-block;

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is putting a div around each label/input combination and setting the css to float left
HTML

```
<form action="#">
    <div>
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="city"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="street">Street</label>
        <input type="text" id="street"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form div{
   float: left
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8RaG/6/)

Comment: the jsfiddle looks like the original code from the question..?

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use `<br />`. It will work for a form as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bootstrap you need to use the css of bootstrap ! 
Use `class="form-horizontal" or class="form-inline"`

You can try this with no css added :

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="city"/>
        <label for="street">Street</label>
        <input type="text" id="street"/>
</form>
```

Simple no ?